# Fatal error in Simple Html Dom on find()

Tags: php, wordpress, simple-html-dom

I am getting the following error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/simple_html_dom.php on line 1114

I've gone through all the topics here and on the net and cannot solve the issue.

I have stored my `file_get_html()` in a `$_SESSION` so that I can use it without always calling the contents of the site (so not to overload them with my requests while developing).

```
$_SESSION['DOMcontent'] = file_get_html('http://example.com');
$html = $_SESSION['DOMcontent'];
```

I've also pulled the file contents to see if I'm getting the right thing

```
$_SESSION['DOMcontent2'] = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
$html2 = $_SESSION['DOMcontent2'];
```

Upon doing a `print_r()` to see what I get in each case, for `$html` I get something like:

```
simple_html_dom Object(
    [root] => 
    [nodes] => Array(
        [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object(
            [nodetype] => 5
            [tag] => root
            [attr]
            => Array()
            [children] => 
            [nodes] => 
            [parent] => 
            [_] => Array(
                [0] => -1
                [1] => 841
                )
            [tag_start] => 0
            [dom : simple_html_dom_node : private] =>
            )
        [1] => simple_html_dom_node Object(
            [nodetype] => 6
            [tag] => unknown
            [attr] => Array()
            [children] => 
            [nodes] => 
            [parent] => 
            [_] => Array(
                [0] => 1
                [4] => 
                )
            [tag_start] => 0
            [dom : simple_html_dom_node : private]
            => 
            )...
```

And when I do a `print_r()` of `$html2` I get the html of the data, which looks like this>

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Random title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/c/bla1.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/c/bla2.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c/bla2.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c/something.css" media="all">
<option value="63059">Some option</option>
```

And the `option` elements repeat (267 of them to be precise).

Now I've put the following:

```
if (!empty($html) && is_object($html)) {
    $option = $html->find('option');
    foreach ( $option as $element) {
        echo $element->value.'<br>';
    }
}
```

And the error appears. I've removed the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` checks, also tried [this fix](https://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/42/), didn't work out.

I don't get it. Is it because I stored my results in a `$_SESSION`? I am getting a non empty object out, should be working.

The simple html dom version is `1.5 ($Rev: 196 $)`. I've put it in my theme, and included the file in my `functions.php` file

```
/********* HTML DOM parser ***********/
require_once( get_template_directory(). '/simple_html_dom.php' );
```

Since I get the contents, this must be working. Any help is appreciated.

## EDIT

The error dissapears when I uncomment the `$_SESSION['DOMcontent'] = file_get_html('http://example.com');` part.

I don't understand. Once I store something in a session, I should be able to use it any way I like it, no? Without having it anymore. When I comment that line I still have simple html dom object in it, but I cannot preform anything on it (use the methods on it from the `simple_html_dom` file). Why is that?

## EDIT 2

Ok, so this is odd, but when I do this

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load($_SESSION['DOMcontent2']);

echo '<div class="info_container">';
if (!empty($html) && is_object($html)) {
    $options = $html->find('option');
    foreach ( $options as $element) {
        $value = $element->value;
        $name = $element->innertext;
        echo '<div>ID: '.$value.'; Name: '.$name.'</div>';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

I get no error. So I scrape the web page with `file_get_contents()` first, put that in a session, then use this in my `simple_html_dom()`, and it will work.

Not sure exactly why, but I guess this will do.

Comment: Are you starting the session before using `$_SESSION` variable? I mean, maybe your `session_start()` call is missing

Comment: No, it's in my template file before `get_header()` function that calls `header.php` file. So no headers are set. Like I said, if I run the code once, and then comment out the par where I pull the contents in my `$_SESSION` I can `print_r` the contents of my session, but cannot use any methods from `simple_html_dom`.